what's the difference between installing libudev and libudev-dev
I'm trying to install pcsc-lite and noticed the documentation said that that libudev is required.

When I attempt to install libudev, I get the following:
$ sudo apt-get install libudev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libudev


However when I install libudev-dev, I have no problems.
$ sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libraspberrypi0 libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libudev-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.



By installing libudev-dev have I also installed libudev?

Are you aware that your distribution probably has pcsclite packages? Try apt install pcsc-tools for example.

Your attempt to install libudev failed, because there is no such package. In Debian and its derivatives (distributions using apt), library packages are generally named in a way that reflects the “soname” of the library, i.e. including an indicator of the library’s ABI “version”. In libudev’s case, the package is named libudev1.
lib… packages without -dev ship library binaries, i.e. everything required for programs which use the library at run-time. There are corresponding -dev packages which ship everything required to build programs relying on the library. These packages generally do not encode a version. In libudev’s case, the package is named libudev-dev, as you discovered. Building with a library also requires the library itself, so -dev packages depend on the matching library package (and are therefore an easy way of installing a library, without having to know the specific name of the library package).
In your setup, installing libudev-dev only installed the -dev package; that’s because libudev1 was already installed. If you’re trying to build pcsc-lite, you need the -dev package anyway.
See difference between libc6-dev and libc6 for another example of this.

Many thanks,  just to be clear for myself, libudev1 is the same as libudev?  Is there a guide somewhere that explains what people mean when they say install libudev.  For instance, is it possible in some cases the library should be cloned and a path directed to it?  TIA s

In practice, yes, it’s the same. If it’s not clear what people mean when they say to install libudev, it’s best to ask them; although in general, if you’re building software you need the development package, if not, just the runtime package. It’s unusual for it to refer to cloning a repository.

If only I could ask, we've sent three support requests to acs but they haven't responded at all.  I guess last question, is libudev part of systemd and can I just clone the libudev folder from here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/main/src/libudev  or should I look elsewhere for the libudev library?

Have you tried with libudev-dev and libudev1? You shouldn’t need to clone anything.

My understanding from your answer is that they are API access wrappers for libudev?

No. libudev1 and libudev-dev are two different parts of libudev: libudev1 provides the runtime library itself (which is what’s needed to run programs requiring libudev), and libudev-dev provides the files needed to build programs requiring libudev. They’re not wrappers, they are libudev.

Thanks @Stephen Kitt I think I need to do a linux refresher course!

Generally speaking, for any given package package:
package is the collection of libraries.
package-dev is the collection of libraries and code for developing the libraries the package package provides.

so does that mean if I am told libudev is a requirement, I must install the libudev library or can I just install libudev-dev?

Unless you need to modify or compile your own versions of the libraries, you usually do not need the -dev package.  If you do, the documentation should call out those additional packages explicitly as requirements.
